# Getting [INFO] core: security barrier not initialized : When Deploying Vault using Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, vault

The error message "core: security barrier not initialized" is appearing when trying to deploy Vault using a Helm chart. I haven't setup the seal How to setup a seal

I'm getting this error. Need a Solution to solve this [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting this message because you haven't [initialized Vault](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/operator/init) yet.  The first thing you'll need to do when Vault is up and running is run the command: `vault operator init`.  If you didn't go about setting up some sort of auto unseal (which it sounds like you didn't), the default seal type is Shamir seal and Vault will give you back 5 unseal keys.  Enter 3 of those keys in with the command `vault operator unseal` and you'll have an unsealed, working Vault instance.

Comment: Thanks Mleon. I tried, 

kubectl exec -ti <POD_NAME> -n <VAULT_NAME> -- vault operator init
kubectl exec -ti <POD_NAME> -n <VAULT_NAME> -- vault operator unseal

It works :)